# Function referring to an instance created by other function C#

Tags: c#, instance

I have a question that may be silly, but I'm new to C#, so pardon my insolence. I am wondering whether it is possible for a function to refer to an instance, which has been created by another function.

I am including an exemplary code to illustrate what I mean:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Instantiator.Instantiate();
        Referent.Refer(instance);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Instance
{
    public void OnInstantiated()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I have been instantiated.");
    }
    public void OnReferred()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I have been referred to.");
    }
}

public class Instantiator
{
    public static void Instantiate()
    {
        Instance instance = new Instance();
        instance.OnInstantiated();
    }
}

public class Referent
{
    public static void Refer(Instance instance)
    {
        if(instance != null)
        {
            instance.OnReferred();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No instance to refer to.");
        }
    }
}
```

What could I use to be able to refer to the "instance" instance (which is created by the Instantiator.Instantiate function) in the Referent.Refer function?

Thanks in advance for your pertinent comments!

Comment: Might be a good idea to read up on [dependency injection](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/615139/An-Absolute-Beginners-Tutorial-on-Dependency-Inver) and loose coupling. Helps think about these sorts of things. Also you should check out the singleton pattern.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make `Instantiator` return the class when done

```
public class Instantiator
{
    public static Instance Instantiate()
    {
        Instance instance = new Instance();
        instance.OnInstantiated();
        return instance;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var instance = Instantiator.Instantiate();
        Referent.Refer(instance);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The pattern `Instantiate()` is doing is often called the "[Factory Pattern](http://www.dotnetperls.com/factory)"

Answer (score 1):

Another option you could use is the [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) pattern. If you also need your instance to be only one, you can give the responsibility to create a new instance and return it afterwards to the class itself.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Instance.Instantiate();
        Referent.Refer(Instance.GetInstance());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Instance
{
    private static Instance myInstance;
    public void OnInstantiated()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I have been instantiated.");
    }
    public void OnReferred()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I have been referred to.");
    }
    public static void Instantiate()
    {
        myInstance = new Instance();
        myInstance.OnInstantiated();
    }
    public static Instance GetInstance()
    {
        return myInstance;
    }
}

public class Referent
{
    public static void Refer(Instance instance)
    {
        if (instance != null)
        {
            instance.OnReferred();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No instance to refer to.");
        }
    }
}
```